# Adding getters and setters dynamically to existing class

Tags: java

Any once suggest me how can I add getters and setters dynamically to existing class? I need to create the instance of same class for further use. I will be having Pojo class at compile time. At run time reading property file and need to create getters and setters those entities

Comment: Reflection can be used to set/get values. (Beware of performance impacts.) Add some details to your question.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"? Without changing the source?

Comment: it's a little difficult to understand - are you looking for a tool to generate java code (text), including getters, setters and constructors?

Comment: I will be having Pojo class at compile time. At run time reading  property file and need to create getters and setters those entities. Its just like updating the existing class file at run time

Comment: Why can't you have those getters and setters at compile time?

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't have a built-in means to add completely new methods.  You could try an embedded scripting engine (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html),  then using Javascript, jRuby, Groovy, etc..  Those languages will allow more runtime functionality along the lines of what you need and should be able to interact with your java code.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper for it:

```
public class MyWrapper extends TheClass {
    private TheClass theClass;

    //getter/setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as stated, as dynamically modifying classes is not allowed.

If there is an interface on the existing class you can use instead, you can use Java's dynamic proxy support to add getters and setters.

```
private static class InstanceProxy implements InvocationHandler {
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) 
      throws Throwable {
        String methodName = method.getName();
        // Do logic based on method name
    }
}
```

And create a proxy with [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance%28java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.Class%5B%5D,%20java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler%29).

These proxy objects will have a given interface and dynamic logic for invoked methods.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, it would be better to have a `Map<String, String>` inside your POJO to load the new properties/values at runtime:

```
public class SomePojo {
    private int intAttribute;
    private String stringAttribute;
    private Map<String, String> dynamicProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();

    //getters and setters...
}

public class BLClass {

    public static void loadProperties(Properties properties, SomePojo pojo) {
        Enumeration<?> enumeration = properties.propertyNames();
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
            String value = properties.getProperty(key);
            pojo.getDynamicProperties().put(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1805079 you're welcome. Since you're new here, please mark this post as an answer by clicking the green mark next to my post =).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done. Usually ORM tools do similar stuff. It is called as byte code weaving / byte code enhancement. You can accomplish it using 3rd party byte code engineering libraries such as BCEL.

Try Googling, here are a few links that would give you more insight on the topic.

[Bytecode Weaving](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=java%20bytecode%20weaving&aq=1&oq=java%20weaving&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) 
[Bytecode Enhancement](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=java+code+enhancement&aq=1&oq=java+code+enh&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)